# Test DOM jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jsdom

I am new in Unit Test JS. I want create test in jasmine. I dynamically create element HTML in JS.

```
 data.map((channel) => {
      const { url, width, height } = channel.thumbnails.medium;
      const { title, customUrl } = channel;
      const { subscriberCount, videoCount, viewCount } = channel.statistics;

      output += `
      <li class="channel-wrraper">
        <a href='${customUrl}' target="_blank">
          <img src='${url}' alt="img-channel" height='${width}' width='${height}' class="channel-img">
        </a>
        <p class="channel-title">${title}</p>
        <div class="channel-statistic">
          <div class="statistic-wrraper">
            <span class="statistic-name">subscribers:</span>
            <span class="subscirber-count">${formatNumber(subscriberCount)}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="statistic-wrraper">
            <span class="statistic-name">videos:</span>
            <span class="video-count">${formatNumber(videoCount)}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="statistic-wrraper">
            <span class="statistic-name">views:</span>
            <span class="veiw-count">${formatNumber(viewCount)}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>`
    });
    channelsList.innerHTML = output;
```

Then some element will be ordered. This is sort function:

```
const list = document.querySelector('.channels-list');

const sortNumber = (selector) => {
  [...list.children]
    .sort((a,b) => a.querySelector(selector).innerText.replace(/,/g, '') - b.querySelector(selector).innerText.replace(/,/g, ''))
    .map(node => list.appendChild(node))
}
```

I read about `JSDOM` and I watched the tutorials in which they tested the DOM, however, these elements were in the html file...

I want test function sortNumber
But I don`t know  how start this task..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [jsdom-global](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global#usage), then you will have `document.body` setup for you:

```js
require('jsdom-global')()

// you can now use the DOM
document.body.innerHTML = 'put your html here'
```

An alternative will be to use [jest](https://jestjs.io/), which comes with JSDOM configured as default